# the proof that characteristic function exist for all distributions

Tags: probability-theory

Claim: characteristic function $\varphi$ exists for any distribution for $X$.

proof: For any $x$ and $t$, $|e^{itX}|^2=1$ and $1$ is integrable. Therefore $E|e^{itX}|^2=1$. It follows that $E|e^{itX}| \leq \sqrt{E|e^{itX}|^2}=1$ and so the function $e^{itx}$ is integrable.

So I don't understand why $E|e^{itX}| \leq \sqrt{E|e^{itX}|^2}$. I'm actually not sure about what $E|e^{itX}|^2$ mean as well, I thought it means $E[|e^{itX}|^2]$, but from the notation, I could as well say that it means $(E[|e^{itX}|])^2$.

Also, why $e^{itX}$ integrable implies that $\varphi$ exists? as the definition of $\varphi$ is not that $e^{itX}$ being integrable but that when you multiply it with $f_x$ is integrable .

Like $\varphi_X(t)=\int_{\mathcal{R}}e^{itx}f_X(x)dx$

or is it because we can also think of $\varphi_X(t)=\int_{\mathcal{R}} e^{itx}dF_X(x)$?

And when integrating with respect to $dF_X(x)$ is the bound of integration from $0 $ to $1$? as that is the range of $F$

Answer (score 2):

> > Claim: characteristic function $\varphi$ exists for any distribution for $X$.
> >
> > proof: For any $x$ and $t$, $|e^{itX}|^2=1$ and $1$ is integrable. Therefore $E|e^{itX}|^2=1$. It follows that $E|e^{itX}| \leq \sqrt{E|e^{itX}|^2}=1$ and so the function $e^{itx}$ is integrable.
> >
> > So I don't understand why $E|e^{itX}| \leq \sqrt{E|e^{itX}|^2}$.

Use Jensen's inequality:
$$(E|e^{itX}|)^2 \le E|e^{itX}|^2$$

and take the square root of both sides.

> > I'm actually not sure about what $E|e^{itX}|^2$ mean as well, I thought it means $E[|e^{itX}|^2]$, but from the notation, I could as well say that it means $(E[|e^{itX}|])^2$.

Your first guess is correct, and that is the convention when dealing with the expectation notation.

> > Also, why $e^{itX}$ integrable implies that $\varphi$ exists? as the definition of $\varphi$ is not that $e^{itX}$ being integrable but that when you multiply it with $f_x$ is integrable .

To say that a variable $Y$ is integrable means that 
$$\int_{\Omega}|Y|dP$$

exists (and it's finite), where $\Omega$ is your sample space and $P$ is the probability measure in that space. Equivalently, after a change of variables, that means that
$$\int_\mathbb{R}|y| dF_Y(y)$$

exists and is finite.

Taking $Y=e^{itX}$, we have that $e^{itX}$ is integrable, because it is dominated by the constant function $1$ (which is integrable).

> > Like $\varphi_X(t)=\int_{\mathcal{R}}e^{itx}f_X(x)dx$

THis is NOT correct in general. It only works if $X$ has a PDF.

> > or is it because we can also think of $\varphi_X(t)=\int_{\mathcal{R}} 
> > e^{itx}dF_X(x)$?

This is basically what happens. See my comments above.

> > And when integrating with respect to $dF_X(x)$ is the bound of integration from $0 $ to $1$? as that is the range of $F$

No, the integral is over all the real line.

Answer (score 0):

The characteristic function $\phi(t)$of a random variable $X$ is defined as expectation value of the random variable $e^{itX}$ i.e., $\phi(t) = E[e^{itX}]= \displaystyle\int_\Omega e^{itx} d\mu$, where $\mu$ is the distribution of $X$.

We know that, $|e^{itX}| = 1$. $$\vert E[e^{itX}]\vert \leq E[|e^{itX}|] = 1$$

This implies that $E[e^{itX}] < \infty$ for any random variable $X$. Thus, characteristic function $\phi(t)$ is well-defined. The well definedness is enough to ensure the existence here.